# Run ember build w/ watch and livereload

Tags: javascript, ember.js, livereload

I'm currently using the command:

```
$ ember build --watch --output-path=../public/
```

to build my ember app. Any ways of achieving the same thing but with a livereload?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just use `ember serve`? It also has `--output-path` if you must have it be `../public/` as opposed to `dist`

```
ember serve --output-path=../public/
```

Comment: Well, because my ember app is served by Koa. Maybe it's not the good way to proceed.

Comment: @Cohars Ah, that's no issue. I've embedded ember inside of the WordPress admin before and live reloaded on that. I just use my own base html but link to the same scripts. Just run ember-serve for the live reload and build portion of it.

Comment: Okay. My original plan was to avoid having to run my Koa app in a terminal tab and ember in an other, but I seems I'll have to.